# CRT Parameter Validation crashes multithreaded debug program

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, visual-studio

The following code works as expected in VS2012, Debug build:

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <assert.h>

DWORD WINAPI childThread(LPVOID param) {
    printf("I'm the child!\n"); fflush(stdout);
    _isatty(-1);
    //assert(1==0);
    return 0;
}

void myInvalidParameterHandler(const wchar_t * expression, const wchar_t * function, const     wchar_t * file, unsigned int line, uintptr_t pReserved) {
    wprintf(L"%s:%i %s() - Invalid parameter [%s]", file, line, function, expression);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) { 
    wprintf(L"Registering invalid parameter handler\n");
    _invalid_parameter_handler newHandler = myInvalidParameterHandler;
    _set_invalid_parameter_handler(newHandler);

    printf("Testing.\n");
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, childThread, NULL, 0, NULL);
    // CreateThread(NULL, 0, childThread, NULL, 0, NULL);
    printf("Thread(s) created, press Enter to exit.\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Parameter Validation will cause a "Abort/Retry/Ignore" popup from the childThread's `_isatty(-1)` and it stays around as long as necessary.  If I hit "Ignore", then myInvalidParameterHandler is invoked, and the program runs until I hit Enter.  All Good.

---

If the second `CreateThread` is uncommented so two Parameter Validation failures occur at once, then the program silently exits.  Sometimes Abort/Retry/Ignore pops up, but it disappears within a second.  The program never hangs around for main's `getchar`.

When run from within the debugger, it hits a breakpoint at:

```
msvcr110d.dll!_CrtDbgBreak() Line 87    C
msvcr110d.dll!_VCrtDbgReportW(int nRptType, void * returnAddress, const wchar_t * szFile, int nLine, const wchar_t * szModule, const wchar_t * szFormat, char * arglist) Line 506   C
msvcr110d.dll!_CrtDbgReportWV(int nRptType, void * returnAddress, const wchar_t * szFile, int nLine, const wchar_t * szModule, const wchar_t * szFormat, char * arglist) Line 262   C++
msvcr110d.dll!_CrtDbgReportW(int nRptType, const wchar_t * szFile, int nLine, const wchar_t * szModule, const wchar_t * szFormat, ...) Line 279 C++
msvcr110d.dll!_isatty(int fh) Line 41   C
assertTest.exe!childThread(void * param) Line 10    C++
```

---

This isn't a general problem of simultaneous assertions.  If I swap commenting of `_isatty(-1)` and `assert(1==0)`, then it does what I'd expect.  We get two abort/retry/ignore popups, they hang around, and the main thread runs to completion.

Release builds don't have this problem, the invalid parameter handler is invoked for both threads and execution always continues.

---

For context, we had a long-running server process that was hitting `_isatty(-1)` in multiple threads and silently exiting.  It's a problem that we've fixed, but this behavior made it very difficult to track down.  I'm wondering if there's something that could be done to help.

I saw a [question with similar behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048377/multithreaded-win32-c-program-crashes-using-try-catch-in-multiple-threads), but that was MinGW & was determined to be a compiler bug.  I've verified that test works in VS2012.

Comment: You are doing this pretty fundamentally wrong.  C++ programmers claim the right to invoke undefined behavior and deal with the consequences of doing so.  This hasn't turned out too well, undefined behavior is a very attractive attack vector for malware.  You probably don't care, your CRT vendor does.  Your _invalid_parameter_handler is **expected** to terminate the program or throw an exception.  You don't do that.  What happens next is, well, *undefined*.

Comment: I agree with you for real code.  This is just a proof of concept (or proof of problem, rather).  The only reason the invalid parameter handler isn't exiting or breaking is to contrast the behavior with the situation where it exited before control got there.

I'm not looking to continue execution when an invalid parameter occurs.  I WANT a DebugBreak to bubble up and I WANT to get a popup about it.  Now that my machine is fixed (as described in my answer), it stops execution AND lets me investigate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - somehow I'd gotten debugging disabled in my registry.  They key `Auto` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug` was missing.  Setting it to `1` caused the debugger named in the `Debugger` key, vsjitdebugger, to be invoked.  Nothing disappears anymore!

Got the idea from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188296 on disabling Watson.

Comment: semi-related: I still wasn't getting any debug popups when running the program from Cygwim, but I did when running from cmd.  This solved that problem: http://superuser.com/questions/197397/no-crash-dialog-when-a-program-crashes-on-cygwin-on-windows-7